# Add a JSON string inside JSON string on Arduino

Tags: json, arduino

I'm developing a project that uses the ESP8266 with ArduinoJson library.
On my webserver I need create a http response with a JSON (read from a file) inside another JSON.
Something like this:

```
String data = "";
String success = "0";

File loadFile = SPIFFS.open(filename, "r");
if (!loadFile){
  Serial.println("Il file non esiste: " + filename);
} else {
  size_t size = loadFile.size();
  if ( size == 0 ) {
    Serial.println("File vuoto: " + filename);
  } else {
    while (loadFile.available()){
      data += char(loadFile.read());
    }

    success = "1";
  }
  loadFile.close();
}

String json;
json = "{\"success\":\"" + String(success) + "\",";
json += "\"form\":\"" + data + "\"}";

server->send(200, "application/json", json);
```

The content of "data" variable is correct but the on client I get:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "data": { }
}
```

Data is empty.
What is the right way to add a JSON string inside another JSON string in "arduino and esp8266"?

Comment: You don't actually need to pretty print that data before you send it.  If you need to be able to read it, just paste it into one of the many pretty-printers on the Internet, like [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: Retrieve the json that's in that `json` variable and show it to us in your question.

Comment: Why are you parsing it, if you just need to send it?

Comment: @gre_gor because I have wrong to copy the code. I have fix it on question.